# Is $\mathbb{R^n}$ the same as $\mathbb{R^{n \times 1}}$, or is there a fundamental difference?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it that $\mathbb{R^{n \times 1}}$ implies we are dealing with a something else, despite an element of $\mathbb{R^{n \times 1}}$ looking exactly the same as $\mathbb{R^n}$. And if there is no difference:
Why would one even take the time to write $\mathbb{R^{n \times 1}}$ instead of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: As always, the context does truly determine what the game is... but, yes, as you evidently suspect, reasonably, the way a thing _naturally_ arose is not quite the most naive form of it. Similarly, the space of maps from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$ _can_ be construed as $m$-by-$n$ matrices, and all that... Or as an innate thing that need not be "identified with" matrices. That is... volitional.

Comment: Probably someone want to emphasis that the element are columns (instead of rows). It is hard to guess, what others think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might write $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ 'column-vectors' instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to explicitly differentiate $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ from its dual, which is representable by $\mathbb{R}^{1\times n},$ 'row-vectors.'

One reason to do this is to make when you are dealing with adjoints explicit; In some technical sense, $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a^\dagger$ are not the same type of object: $a^\dagger$ is a bounded linear function $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, whereas $a$ is just something that $a^\dagger$ might act on.

Comment: I'm new to stack-exchange, and I don't know if this is the place to thank you, but thank you! I understand the 'necessity' now :)

Comment: @SliemelEla The way to thank someone for an answer is to accept it (the check mark). You can also upvote it (the up arrow). You can upvote more than one answer. You can also upvote other questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

As a set or a topological space, elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are usually written as $n$-tuples $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$. As a vector space, elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are written either as column vectors $$\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots\\a_n\end{bmatrix} \tag{*}$$
or also as $n$-tuples $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ and I've seen $\langle a_1, \dotsc, a_n \rangle$ as well.

The space of $m$-by-$n$ matrices ($m$ rows and $n$ columns) with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ is sometimes denoted $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. With this convention, a typical element of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ would be an $n$-by-$1$ column matrix, notationally indistinguishable from the vector in (*).